# Why does 'Access My Data Anytime,' permission show as an 'Optional Permission'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

How do we get this permission to be in our default permissions to gain an access token and not be a revokable, optional permission?

Been using Facebook Connect and am asking for basic permissions such as a user's ID, name, profile pic, interests, likes, education, etc. All of these permissions access a user's basic information. I've seen where apps ask for these along with the Access Data Anytime permission as a non-revokable permission. However, mine is coming up as a revokable permission that I'm afraid people won't allow.

Answer (score 2):

offline_access is an extended permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#extended_perms). The present facebook auth dialog makes all extended permissions optional - so the user can pick and chose the extended permissions he/she wishes to grant to the app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#perms).

That said, offline_access is being deprecated and hence you should move to the design where you extend the permissions by swapping normal tokens with long-live tokens. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ or other stackoverflow questions like [Facebook offline access step-by-step](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step) to understand more about it.